# How to prevent loading Jquery files from _layout view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using mvc and in some views i don't need to load jquery files from _layout

So I need to stop  loading Jquery files from _layout view in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of your default layout `_LayoutWithoutJQuery.cshtml` that dosn't the have jQuery files then in your Views when you don't want to use the default layout you can use

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithoutJQuery.cshtml";
}
```